# While sending mail with phpmailer it also send github with it, how to remove it?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I can send email with phpmailer perfectly but while i check "Show Original" in gmail it show me that there is a github link in my From address, like bellow:

```
From:   Tamjid Hasan <tamjid8@gmail.com> Using PHPMailer 6.0.6 (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)
```

I want to know how to remove that github link. Anyone help me please.

Comment: Have you checked the PHPMailer help pages? https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The text you're seeing there comes from the `X-Mailer` header of the mail. In PHPMailer this can be defined with `$mail->XMailer = "Your awesome mailer"`.

If you check the source of the PHPMailer code you will find the following:

```
/**
 * What to put in the X-Mailer header.
 * Options: An empty string for PHPMailer default, whitespace for none, or a string to use.
 *
 * @var string
 */
public $XMailer = '';
```

This means you could also set `XMailer` to `' '` to disable the header.